# AngularJS components

Tags: angularjs

Начинаю учить первый ангуляр и надолго застрял на проблеме байндинга. Сразу приложу весь свой код: [https://plnkr.co/edit/irj9iZiWYY6ctZph3Cwb](https://plnkr.co/edit/irj9iZiWYY6ctZph3Cwb?p=preview)

По структуре проекта понятно, что parent компонент выводит данные, а child компонент (являясь зависимостью parent) выполняет роль добавления новых данных.

Метод добавления новых данных остается в parent, т.к. именно этот мой компонент считается "умным" и хранит данные.

```
<child-add on-add="$ctrl.appendData()" />
```

В child элемент я передаю этот коллбэк, чтобы вызвать его при сабмите формы добавления новых данных. В файле child.component.js в функции `onSubmit` я хочу вызвать `ctrl.onAdd`, но как я понял, я **не могу туда передать аргументом новые данные** ([прочитал тут](http://www.codelord.net/2016/05/13/understanding-angulars-and-binding/))

Вопрос: как тогда передать данные из child в parent компонент? Хочу сразу научиться делать это правильно.

И еще: если не использовать ES6 синтаксис (классы), я верно оформляю код? Стоит ли `this` обзывать `ctrl`, чтобы использовать его в функциях? Функции типа `onSubmit` стоит писать прямо внутри функции контроллера?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете передать любые параметры.

`child.component.js`

```
function onSubmit() {
  ctrl.onAdd({text: ctrl.formData.text});
}
```

`parent.component.js`

```
<child-add on-add="$ctrl.appendData(text)" />
```

Далее в контроллере в функцию `appendData` будет передан ваш параметр.

Если используете es6, то надобность в `ctrl` отпадает по 2 причинам:

1. Теперь `ctrl` нужно определять в каждом методе класса, что очень неудобно
2. В es6 есть `=>` (fat-arrow) что позволяет привязать контекст вызова и внутри функции мы будем иметь "правильный" `this`